# Help with retURL after saveURL and save_new_url

Tags: url, urlhacking

I have created a custom button using URL (I am aware that it is not Lightning Ready). With the button, the user is taken to an edit page of a Child record of the Opportunity (Object X), then after saving that record the user is taken to Select Record Type of a Child of Object X (Object Y), then to the edit page of Object Y record;

Opportunity --> Edit page for Object X record --> Save --> Select Record Type for Object Y record --> Edit page for Object Y record --> Save

It all works fine, until I try to add retURL after saveURL and save_new_url. I would like to take the user back to the Opportunity record or even the Object X record if possible. Here is my working URL without any retURL after save;

```
/a00/e?retURL={!Opportunity.Id}&RecordType=012200000000Tpv&ObjectXfield={!Opportunity.Account&ObjectXfield _lkid={!Opportunity.AccountId}&ObjectXfield ={!Opportunity.Name}&ObjectXfield _lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&ObjectXfield ={!Opportunity.Account}&ObjectXfield={!Account.Booking_Office_Details__c}&ObjectXfield _lkid={!Account.Booking_Office_DetailsId__c}&saveURL=%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Frecordtypeselect.jsp%3Fent%3DObjectY%0A%26save_new_url%3D%2FObjectYprefix%2Fe%3F
```

Any assistance to add the retURl after my saves would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: FYI URL buttons are lightning ready depending on what they are doing

Comment: Add the RetUrl param and value as part of the save_new_url making sure to urlEncode it

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for the feedback. I get the following error when i do that: <&saveURL=%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Frecordtypeselect.jsp%3Fent%3D01I0J000000SuCm%0A%26save_new_url%3D%2Fa6h%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%7B!Opportunity.Id%7D>   "Invalid Page Redirection
The page you attempted to access has been blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator for assistance. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors"

Comment: looks like you encoded the {} as part of the URL